# Unable to get ESP8266 AT codes to work from sketch

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I have a problem using AT commands via my Sketch.

I flashed the ESP-01 unit I have, and when connecting the unit directly to my RX and TX pins on the Arduino mega, I can use the AT commands via serial monitor. However as soon as I try to move the pins and use SoftwareSerial.h on any other pins, I can communicate with the module.

I have looked at examples, from really basic to full on web services, and none of them work, if I connect the RX and TX from the ESP to my Arduino in the correct locations as defined. The AT commands are not processed.

I have tried swapping the RX and TX connections, still with no results. I know the AT commands work, as I can manually enter them, just not using a sketch.

Below is one of the may examples I tried with no results at all.

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    
    SoftwareSerial mySerial(2,3); //RX,TX
    
    void setup(){
      Serial.begin(115200);
      mySerial.begin(115200);
      delay(1000);
      mySerial.write("AT\r\n");
      long b=mySerial.read();
      Serial.println(b);
      delay(1000);
      mySerial.print("AT\r\n");
      b=mySerial.read();
      Serial.println(b);
      delay(1000);
      mySerial.println("AT\r\n");
      b=mySerial.read();
      Serial.println(b);
      delay(1000);
     
    }
    
    void loop(){
      if(Serial.available()>0){
        byte b=Serial.read();
        mySerial.println(b);
      }
      if(mySerial.available()>0){
        byte b=mySerial.read();
        Serial.println(b);
      }
    }
```

Looking at serial monitor I get these results.

```
09:32:47.346 -> -1
09:32:48.346 -> -1
09:32:49.331 -> -1
```

When I connect directly to my RX and TX pins I can run AT commands like below

```
    
    09:54:32.148 -> AT
    
    09:54:32.148 -> 
    09:54:32.148 -> OK
    09:54:39.175 -> AT+GMR
    
    09:54:39.175 -> AT version:1.1.0.0(May 11 2016 18:09:56)
    09:54:39.175 -> SDK version:1.5.4(baaeaebb)
    09:54:39.175 -> Ai-Thinker Technology Co. Ltd.
    09:54:39.175 -> Jun 13 2016 11:29:20
    09:54:39.175 -> OK
```

I don't know where I am going wrong here, for some reason it does not seem like my ESP-01 likes "Software Serial". I have 5 units all of them giving the same results. Showing me its something I am doing wrong.
With all of this said, how do I get my AT commands to work from my sketch? do i have to reset the unit in setup, or is my code just completely wrong?

This is just testing, AT commands. If I get this to work I can add the rest of the code. Since there is no point in writing a entire sketch if I cant get the basic command to work.

Comment: not all pins of Mega support SoftwareSerial and SoftwareSerial is unreliable at 115200 baud. use one of the other 3 hardware Serials of Mega. Serial1 for example. the pins are label RX1 and TX1 on board

Comment: Thank you for this, I changed the BAUD rate to 9600 and changed the pins to Serial1, and Finally managed to get commands sent to the ESP01

Comment: why did you change the baud rate? the AT firmware uses 115200 baud

Comment: sorry, this historical version maybe uses 9600 baud

Comment: I know I could have left it as is, but found that the hardware I am interfacing with does not support 115200 so had to change it.